# Identifying specific data based on earlier data SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I'm currently working on a query with a DB2 database that needs to identify specific movements of people between different locations on certain dates.  Normally, this isn't much of an issue, but in this particular case, the movements in question rely on the existence of certain movements that occurred before them.  I'm fairly new to SQL, so this has me all kinds of turned around.

As an example, think of something like this:
We are calling data from tables named Profile and ExternalMovement.  Profile contains Name, ID, and other identifying data, while ExternalMovement contains Date, Location, Movement.  There are locations numbered 1 - 3, and types of movements A - C.  Suppose we had in our tables the following data:

```
| Name  | Date       | Location | Movement |
|-------|------------|----------|----------|
| Kelly | 01/03/2013 | 2        | A        |
| Kelly | 01/02/2013 | 3        | C        |
| Mark  | 01/02/2013 | 2        | A        |
| Mark  | 01/03/2013 | 2        | B        |
| Mark  | 01/09/2013 | 1        | A        |
| Kelly | 01/11/2013 | 1        | C        |
| Kelly | 01/12/2013 | 3        | B        |
| Mark  | 01/14/2013 | 3        | C        |
```

What I want to do is be able to call up all C type movements where the last movement was not also a C type, resulting in something like:

```
| Name  | Date       | Location | Movement |
|-------|------------|----------|----------|
| Kelly | 01/02/2013 | 3        | C        |
| Mark  | 01/14/2013 | 3        | C        |
```

To make things even more fun, in case any solutions require writing tables, I do not have table-write privileges, so work-arounds are necessary.  My current iteration of code works to a degree, but it isn't very efficient as far as I can tell.  Essentially, I specify the code I want for the data to be pulled, then perform a select(max) on the same data set, restricting it to dates before the earlier specified.

```
SELECT A.Name, EX.Date, EX.Location, EX.Movement From Profile A
JOIN ExternalMovement EX ON EX.ID = A.ID AND Movement = 'C'
JOIN ExternalMovement PRIOR on PRIOR.ID = EX.ID
AND PRIOR.Date = (SELECT MAX(PRIOR1.Date) ON ExternalMovement PRIOR1 
WHERE PRIOR1.ID = EX.ID AND PRIOR1.Date < EX.Date AND PRIOR1.Movement <> 'C')
```

Now, the real thing is of course much more complicated, and I can post the actual code if necessary, but I'm hoping that this simpler example is enough to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select pem.*
from (select . . . ,
             lag(em.movement) over (partition by p.name order by em.date) as prev_movement
      from Profile p join
           ExternalMovement em
           on em.ID = p.ID
     ) pem
where movement = 'C' and (prev_movement <> 'C' or prev_movement is null);
```

Comment: Ok, I can see how that would work based on the example and my limited understanding (little over a month total).  Basically, you are breaking everything apart by name, then ordering them by date.  From there, you pick the ones that fit the movement criteria and use the lag () to look at the one below it to see if it meets our other filter criteria, correct?

Comment: @Ildaen . . . I would simply say that the `lag()` is getting the previous movement for each name.  The outer `where` is applying the logic you want.